Dax measure error in a table with 100 rows but not in one with 50 rows
I have the following PowerBI file with 2 tables.
Formula 100rows vs 50rows
One of the tables contains 50 rows, and the other contains 100 (both tables have the same values; only the number of repeated rows changes).
I also have the following formula:
Indis = SUMX(
             FILTER( ‘Table50rows’,
                     ‘Table50rows’[cfId] = 10029 ),
             VALUE(‘Table50rows’[fieldValue]) 
             )

The problem is that the formula works correctly with the table of 50 rows, but it gives me the following error with the table of 100 rows:
MdxScript(Model) (17,5) Calculation error in measure: Cannot convert value 'N0' of type Text to type Number.

This is definitely weird. I don't see any difference in query plans or column encodings and don't know what else to look for.

I have spoken to Jeffrey Wang (the father of DAX) and he has provided the definitive answer. Quoted below with his permission:

This is due to different execution strategies of the Vertipaq Engine
that doesn't guarantee that VALUE() is called after the where clause.
To guarantee VALUE() is called only when safe, use the SUMX(..., IF())
pattern: SUMX('Table100rows', IF('Table100rows'[cfId] = 10029,
VALUE('Table100rows'[fieldValue])))
This applies to all aggregation expressions pushed to the Vertipaq
Engine. Aggregation expressions should not assume that the where
clause is applied first; instead, they should ensure their own safety
during execution. I am not implying that aggregation expressions will
be evaluated during execution while ignoring the where clause, which
is clearly a performance concern. It's just that the expression may be
evaluated during the Vertipaq Engine's preparation phase against some
values without the where clause being applied.


Seems weird then that the official SUMX documentation doesn't mention this, considering the example they use is SUMX(FILTER(InternetSales, InternetSales[SalesTerritoryID]=5),[Freight]) which should also throw an error.

Yes but there is plenty not documented about DAX on the official MS help pages. SQLBI have updated DAX.guide as a result of this.

This is a strange one and I'd be interested to hear the thoughts of others. I would also raise this with Microsoft as the behaviour is strange. The cut off is 65 rows BTW (64 works fine and 65 throws the issue). Even using a slicer makes no difference.
Could this be to do with eager v strict evaluation in the SUMX()? I have no idea and would be interested in other theories (further reading: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-eager-vs-strict-evaluation-in-dax/).
For the record, this forces your measure to work:
Indis_2 = 
VAR x =     
    FILTER(
        'Table100rows',
        'Table100rows'[cfId] == 10029
    )
VAR y = ADDCOLUMNS(x, "@test", 1)
RETURN

SUMX(
    y,
    VALUE('Table100rows'[fieldValue])
)

Simply forcing the evaluation of the filter by adding a dummy column means the measure now works.

Easiest workaround I found was to just add IFERROR(VALUE(‘Table100rows’[fieldValue]), 0) and ignore the rows throwing an error in the SUM.

Yes, that's another option. The real question is why this is happening at all. The filter should contain a single row only and not throw any errors.
